# How can I style the sub-menu background color?

Tags: css, wordpress

This sounds like it might be a Wordpress question, but I was told at the Worpress Exchange that it's a generic CSS question and that that's off-topic for the Wordpress Exchange site. Before someone closes this as off-topic for Stack Overflow, can you look at it long enough to determine if it's just a generic CSS question? (The theme I'm using doesn't provide support for child theme development either, so I'm out of routes to get help.)

I'm trying to change the default menu appearance (in Wordpress using the Genesis theme, but again, try to hold off the assumption this is anything beyond generic CSS before someone looks at it long enough to determine that). For instance, by default the menu shows black text on a white background. I'd like to **change that** to **white text on a green background.** I looked at the markup in my browser's developer's tools window. (The markup is at the end of this post.)

First I made these changes to the main button menus. It wasn't hard to come up with this.

```
li.menu-item a {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #18ddb1;
}
```

But this didn't change the background of the sub-menus (the ones that drop down when you hover over the main menu buttons).

I tried using the above CSS with other selectors, like `.sub-menu li`, `.sub-menu a`, and a number of other combinations, but nothing changed the background color of the drop-down sub-menus. What am I doing wrong?

```
<nav id="genesis-nav-primary" 
     class="nav-primary genesis-responsive-menu">
  <div class="wrap">
    <ul id="menu-mine" 
        class="menu genesis-nav-menu menu-primary js-superfish sf-js-enabled
               sf-arrows"
        style="touch-action: pan-y;">
      <li id="menu-item-??" 
          class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type
                 menu-item-object-page menu-item-??">
        <a class="sf-with-ul" href="...">
          <span itemprop="name"> ...menu item text... </span>
        </a>
        <button class="sub-menu-toggle>
        </button>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li id="menu-item-??" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type
                 menu-item-object-page menu-item-??">
            <a href="...">
              <span> .. menu item text .. </span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>                  
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Try: `li.menu-item a, #menu-mine .sub-menu menu-item`

Comment: can you post the current style selector that is being applied (using Chrome dev tools simply "Inspect" that `a` and look at the CSS rules being applied to that element)? Sounds like you just need a more specific selector... the current one probably uses some `>` selectors or something that taking precedence. Or just throw on an `!important` like every other frusterated developer does lol (not recommeneded)

Comment: It's a drop-down menu. I can't get it to stay down while I click on the markup to apply the inspector. Does that matter to what I'll see in the inspector?

Comment: @composerMike you can force `:hover` state in [Chrome dev tools](https://coderwall.com/p/s_g9qg/use-chrome-dev-tools-to-force-element-state-hover-debugging). But I don't think that is necessary for your case. Simply inspect one of the the `li.menu-item a` and click the node to see the styles. Shouldn't matter if its hover or not because its not a hover style you are trying to change